# Remelt/dissolve waterproofed circuit board epoxy

Tags: integrated-circuit

I'm trying to fix a washing machine. Its circuit board is embedded in epoxy to waterproof it. Its been sitting in 100+ degree heat and the error code resolved, leading me to think thermal expansion fixed a connection issue.

Is there a safe and practical way to melt and remove the epoxy around the component?

Comment: Generally I bake the circuit board in an oven to around 90Centigrade then carefully carve off the epoxy. The high temperature makes it go ‘chalky’ so it carves easily. It is necessary to repeat the process to remove all the epoxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the epoxy or potting material, your best bet is to try a spot check with a heat gun. There are other ways to get potting material to soften up. A few are, use IPA or acetone (not recommended as it can damage components) to soften the material and then chip it away.